# Rails 4 essential training : redirection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

hi I'm getting the following error:

Unknown action
The action 'other_hello' could not be found for DemoController

after typing this redirection code (which is exactly the same as shown in Rails 4 essential training)
I'm using rails version 4.2.0

```
def other_hello
  redirect_to(:controller => 'demo', :action => 'index')
end

def lynda
  redirect_to('http://lynda.com')
end
```

so basically its not redirecting me for some reason?

route.rb has the following route:

```
  root 'demo#index'

   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get
```

The server gives the following error:

Started GET "/demo/other_hello" for ::1 at 2015-01-16 04:47:25 +0800

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'other_hello' could not be found for DemoController):

It shows no sign of redirection anywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

So what that means is that your route demands aren't finding a suitable action on your controller. Double-check the spelling of your controller inside the file, which would be either `DemoController` or (preferably) the pluralized `DemosController`.

**Edit**:

What's happening is that your rails router is directing your application to an unknown path. Edit your rails router to look something like this:

`match '/other_hello', to: 'demo#other_hello', via: :get`

Every major action you take in your Rails application (save for a few edge cases) will begin at your router and work its way downward to your views. Rails will throw an `UnknownAction` error when it can't find where it needs to go to complete your request. In this case you just hadn't yet instructed it where to go.

Make those changes, and make sure to restart your server; you'll want to do that every time you change the routing in your Rails app.

**Edit 2**:

If you want a nicer way to write your redirect in the `other_hello` action, simply put `redirect_to root_path`. You'll learn more about paths as you go along, but just know that `root_path` is the representation of your homepage in your application, where you wrote: `root 'demo#index'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply GravesColin, but changing the file names is not working. can't figure out a solution

Comment: Do you have any more code you can post to your question? I'd love to try and help you!

Comment: Dear @CollinGraves,
thank you so much, I've been waiting for a response. I cannot find a solution anywhere on the internet and I'm totally new to coding.
Have edited the above question and added more code, if there are any specifics you require please let me know. 
appreciate it!

Comment: Ah! I understand. I'll edit my comment above so you can accept it when your problem is solved :)

Comment: Thanks Collin,
but it's still giving me the same error (The action 'other_hello' could not be found for DemoController ) if I use the first route which is 
   match '/other_hello', to: 'demo#other_hello', via: :get
and with the second one          redirect_to root_path
its giving me a routing error. Also, in the routes tutorial the redirection code or other_hello code is not mentioned anywhere in the routes.rb file that he writes. Is this something to do with the version 4.2.0 that I'm working with that I have to add a redirect path or other_hello in routes.rb? Even if I do it's not working :(

Comment: seems that rails is not returning a status code to the browser to redirect, as there is no mention of redirection in the server.